# Several if statements - some won't work - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

With the code like this, the first four loops work fine. The two on the bottom don't.

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        if(selected.x<5){
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (1,0,0);
    }
}
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        if(selected.x>-5){
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (-1,0,0);
    }
}
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        if(selected.z<5){
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (0,0,1);
    }
}
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        if(selected.z>-5){
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (0,0,-1);
    }   
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        print("escape");
        currentState=BattleStates.NONE;
        gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().PlayerChoice();
        gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().ShowMenu();

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        print("pressed");
        destination=selected;
        currentState=BattleStates.NONE;
        gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().Resolution();

    }
```

If i move the two last ones to the top, they will work, but not the four ones that were moved to the bottom. I can't see an explanation for this. 
Anyone?

Comment: You do not close `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))`, before you start the next one with `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))`. If you used proper formatting, you would'we spotted this issue right away. Your IDE should already provide an option to properly align code, start using it.

Comment: there is no loop, and brackets don't quite match. please post code that parses

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this section of code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
    if(selected.z>-5){
    selected=selected + new Vector3 (0,0,-1);
}
```

Due to the indent style you're using, it is difficult to see which opening bracket goes with which closing bracket. As a result, you are missing a closing bracket and so the following functions are being contained within this one.

If this is already a problem you are encountering with simple `if` functions, you will likely struggle once the code becomes more complex.

Consider using the Allman indent style. Doing so would make your code look like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    if(selected.x<5)
    {
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (1,0,0);
    }
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    if(selected.x>-5)
    {
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (-1,0,0);
    }
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    if(selected.z<5)
    {
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (0,0,1);
    }
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
{
    if(selected.z>-5)
    {
        selected=selected + new Vector3 (0,0,-1);
    }
    // Here you can easily see that the closing bracket is missing.

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
{
    print("escape");
    currentState=BattleStates.NONE;
    gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().PlayerChoice();
    gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().ShowMenu();
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    print("pressed");
    destination=selected;
    currentState=BattleStates.NONE;
    gameManager.GetComponent<gameManager>().Resolution();
}
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it as your accepted answer, thank you.